# Getting a server control property value via Java Script

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want to access a boolean property of my User Control through Java Script. For this I do:

```
..=document.getElementById('<%= dtPickerBirth.ClientID%>').IsValidDate;
```

As you might guess IsValidDate is a boolean value and I want to access it. Is there anything wrong with this code? I use this for validation purposes but it does not work.

Comment: That property will only be available on the server side, so if you really need that you'll have to use ajax. Looks like you should implement a separate client-side validation layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about `..= '<%= dtPickerBirth.IsValidDate %>';` ?

Comment: Yeah, body, that really does the job except it seems as boolean values in Java Script and C# are different. Why? Because I assign the IsValidDate property to args.IsValid. And on validation I get browser error."False is undefined". I see this when debugging. IsValidDate returns False but there's problem in setting this value to args.IsValid.

Comment: I think you have to parse the value returned by the IsValidDate by hand in the javascript side, instead of assigning it directly to args.IsValid

Comment: How can I check <%= dtPickerBirth.IsValidDate%> value and act accordingly?

Comment: var isValidDate = '<%= dtPickerBirth.IsValidDate %>';
if(isValidDate == 'True')
{
 args.IsValid = true;
}
else
{
        args.IsValid = false;
}

Comment: Please check if you are getting False in the variable. Also, this code can be optimized...